# conditional relationship / query based on table attribute

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have the following tables

```
categories
- id
- parent_id

threads
- id
- title
- category_id
- updated_at
```

The categories table consists of children and parent categories and each thread belongs to a children category.

For each category ( either parent or children ) i want to fetch the thread that was most most recently updated. Therefore, when i query all categories, i need to have an extra field which contains the title of that thread.

To better illustrate this, i will give an example.

- **parent_categoty** = iOS
- **children_category** = iOS13
- **children_category** = iOS14

Now when i fetch all categories (iOS, iOS13 and iOS14 ), i want to have an extra field named 'recentThread'. However since threads belong to **children_categories**, the **parent_category** doesn't have any thread associated with it, but instead for the **parent_category** i want to fetch the most recent thread among its children categories.

Therefore i need to use a different relationship based on whether the **parent_id** is **NULL**.

```
public method recentThreadForParent(){

return $this->hasOneThrough(
            Thread::class,
            Category::class,
            'parent_id',
            'category_id'
        )->latest('updated_at');
}
```

```
public method recentThreadForChildren(){
 return $this->hasOne(Thread::class)->latest('updated_at');
}
```

After i did a research i found the following

```
public method scopeWithRecentTrhead($query){

 if ($this->parent_id == null ){

  // do something
}
else {

 // do something else
}
}
```

But it is always null so it enters always the firs condition.

On top of that i want in the end to have the same name for either relationship in order to be able to access the recent thread like this

```
$category->recentThread
```

Where category can be either parent or children. The solution that i found for this is to use **addSelect**

```
public method scopeWithRecentThread($query){

// For the children category
 $query->addSelect([
 'recentThread' => Thread::select('title')
                   ->whereColumn('category_id', 'categories.id)
                   ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                   ->limit(1)
 ]);

// For the parent category i'm not sure how to do it because i need the ids of the children for each parent category 
 $query->addSelect([
 'recentThread' => Thread::select('title')
                   ->whereIn('category_id', 'Ids of children')
                   ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                   ->limit(1)
 ]);

}
```

and in that case i don't know how to conditionally execute a different query.
i've tried to use **when** but what i need to achieve is something like

```
$query->when('parent_id is NOT NULL')
```

But that doesn't work either

Comment: Can children have children categories?

Comment: one option is that you can map the result of the query and then in the map closure get the threads with the required condition